# Search all the values in the searchQuerys list and get all the values that appear in the title or the content columns using Python and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite

I need to search all the values in the searchQuerys list and get all the values that appear in the title or the content columns using Python and sqlite.

searchQuerys= ["apples", "banana", "fig"]
searchQuerys= ["apples", "banana"]

The following code works fine, but I don't like it and I feel it is prone to SQL injection. is there a way to enhance it?

```
selectStmt = "select id, content, title from table where (content like '%"+searchQuerys[0] +"%' or title like '%" + searchQuerys[0] + "%')"
            i=1
            while i < len(searchQuerys):
                selectStmt += " and (content like '%"+searchQuerys[i] +"%' or title like '%" + searchQuerys[i] + "%')"
                i+=1
            print(selectStmt)
            res = conn.execute (selectStmt)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect(":memory:")

# just for debugging
connection.set_trace_callback(print)

cursor = connection.cursor()
search_queries = ["apples", "banana", "fig"]
select_statement = (
    "select id, content, title from table_name where {where_clause}".format(
        where_clause=" OR ".join(
            "(content like ? or title like ?)"
            for i in range(len(search_queries))
        )
    )
)
# duplicating params + wrapping with percent signs
params = [
    "%{}%".format(search_term)
    for tup in zip(search_queries, search_queries)
    for search_term in tup
]
response = cursor.execute(select_statement, params)
```